# Not able to run gremlin shell on open JDK

Tags: orientdb

I am using a Mac (Mac OS 10.13.6) and I am using Open JDK openjdk version "1.8.0_192"

I can easily run the Orient Database by running server.sh

But when I try to run gremlin.sh I get an error

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib: dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I resolved it after a some googling. The solution on Mac OS (which worked for me is)

```
brew cask upgrade
```

This upgraded to a new version of open JDK which doesn't has this problem.

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/42